# What type is it in Kotlin？

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

when i covert the API response to object, the data would be wrong. I have no idea.
My API response is `Any` type.Every data is correct without number data.
for example

```
D/OKHttp:
result":[
  0,
  {"memory": {
             "distribution":"OpenWrt"
             "total":1037029376,
             "shared":253952,
             "free":946176000,
             "cached":27062272,
             "available":933396480,
             "buffered":2101248
             },
             {
             ...
             }
  }
]
```

when i Covert to Any type

```
D/InfoAdapter: result":[0,{"memory":{"distribution":"OpenWrt", total=1.037029376E9, shared=253952.0, free=9.46176E8, cached=2.7062272E7, available=9.3339648E8, buffered=2101248.0},...}]
```

The number data(`1.037029376E9`) look like a type, But i have no idea what type is it. Any i don't know how to covert these to Int.
Is anyone can handle this？

Comment: looks like a `Double`

Comment: Oh, yes. I made it. 
It double, Thank you very much.